# prove or disprove: if the limits of $(a_n + b_n)$ and $(a_n*b_n)$ exists, the limit of $(a_n^2+b_n^2)$ also exists.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm not even sure if I know whether this is actually true or not and I couldn't find a counter example.

Comment: Try applying arithmetic operations to the first two sequences to obtain the third.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that
$$
(a_n+b_n)^2=a_n^2+2a_nb_n+b_n^2.
$$
Hence,
$$
a_n^2+b_n^2=(a_n+b_n)^2-2a_nb_n.
$$
Using the continuity of the function $f(x)=x^2$ and the [properties of limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties), we obtain
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n^2+b_n^2)=(\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n))^2-2\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_nb_n).
$$